# How to read one line of text at a time and write back out to another file in VB6

Tags: string, vb6

I'm trying to read from file "A" one line at a time, make changes to that line, and write it back out to file "B". Appending File "B" as I go. I've found plenty of info on the web but none of it matches what I'm looking for.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I threw this together real quick, but it should be pretty easy to read.  You open your file to read, and your file to write to, and iterate through it.

```
Dim fileIn As Integer
Dim fileOut As Integer
Dim sLine As String

fileIn = FreeFile

Open "C:\Temp\input.txt" For Input As fileIn

fileOut = FreeFile

Open "C:\Temp\output.txt" For Append As fileOut

Do While Not EOF(fileIn)
    Line Input #fileIn, sLine
    sLine = sLine & " has been changed"  ' This is where you'd make your changes
    Print #fileOut, sLine
Loop

Close fileIn
Close fileOut
```

Comment: Don't use that "FreeFile + 1" idea.  FreeFile() is a function that returns an available slot in VB6's file control block table.  Adding one to the value risks colliding with a file number already in use.

Comment: @Bob -- Thanks for pointing that out, I forgot about that.  I've edited my answer in response.

Comment: `Close fileNum` -> `Close fileIn`

Comment: This can also be a little faster if you tell VB6 to use its maximum sequential I/O buffer size.  Add Len = 32767 to the end of the Open statements.