# Read words/phrases from a file, make distinct, and write out to another file, in Java

Tags: java, file, sorting, distinct-values

I have a text file with a word or phrase on each line. How do I:

- Read those phrases into memory,
- Make distinct (eliminate duplicates),
- Sort alphabetically,
- Write the results back out to a file?

StackOverflow has answers for similar Questions in other languages such as [C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277748/how-to-read-inputs-from-a-file-and-to-write-outputs-to-another-file-in-c), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20366124/how-to-read-a-file-in-php-then-write-only-certain-lines-back-out-to-another-fil), Python, [Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16855982/how-read-a-file-and-write-another-file-in-prolog), and [VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928301/how-to-read-one-line-of-text-at-a-time-and-write-back-out-to-another-file-in-vb6). But I cannot find one for Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage:

- [NIO (Non-blocking I/O)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_I/O_%28Java%29) API (available since Java 7)
- [Streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) API (available since Java 8)

…to solve the problem elegantly:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
  Path input = Paths.get("/Users/yourUser/yourInputFile.txt");
  Path output = Paths.get("/Users/yourUser/yourOutputFile.txt");

  try {
   List<String> words = getDistinctSortedWords(input);
   Files.write(output, words, UTF_8);
  } catch (IOException e) {
    //log error and/or warn user
  }
}

private static List<String> getDistinctSortedWords(Path path) throws IOException {
  try(Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path, UTF_8)) {
    return lines.map(String::trim)
            .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()) // If keyword is not empty, collect it.
            .distinct()
            .sorted()
            .collect(toList());
  }
}
```

Note: requires static imports

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toList;
```

Answer (score 1):

The following Java 8 example code should help. It is neither robust nor well-tested. And it assumes all your data can fit easily in memory. While not perfect, this example should get you going in the right direction.

The [Java Collections Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)) defines the [Set interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_collections_framework#Set_interfaces) for collecting a distinct bunch of values. As an implementation of that interface, we will use [`HashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html).

Note that we make an attempt to trim any white space from each line. Unfortunately, the `String::trim` method does not do a thorough job of this. In real work I would replace that call with a call to a better library for trimming, such as [Google Guava](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava). You probably want to remove *all* non-printing characters.

We test each string with the `isEmpty` method to filter out any strings without any characters.

The following code uses the [Try-With-Resources syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to automatically close any open file.

```
// Read file.
// For each line, trim string. 
// Add to Set to make collection of distinct values.
// Convert to List, and sort.
// Write back values to text file.

Set< String > set = new HashSet<>( );

String path = "/Users/yourUser/yourInputFile.txt";
File file = new File( path );
try ( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( file ) ) ) {
    String line;
    while ( ( line = br.readLine( ) ) != null ) {
        // Process the line.
        String keyword = line.trim( );
        if ( ! keyword.isEmpty( ) ) {  // If keyword is not empty, collect it.
            set.add( keyword );
        }
    }
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace( );
}
```

Now we have a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of distinct values. To sort them, we need to convert to a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html). The [`Collections`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class (notice the "s") offers a static method for [sorting a List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) of items that implement [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

```
List< String > keywords = new ArrayList< String >( set );
Collections.sort( keywords );
```

Let’s write that sorted list to a file in storage.

```
// Write to file. 
// Use Try-With-Resources to automatically close the file if opened.
try ( 
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter( "/Users/yourUser/yourOutputFile.txt" ) ;
) {
    for ( String k : keywords ) {
        writer.write( k + "\n" );  // You may want a different newline instead of the Unix-style LINE FEED hard-coded here with "\n".
    }
} catch ( IOException e ) {
    e.printStackTrace( );
}
```

See the results on the console, if you wish.

```
System.out.println( "Size: " + keywords.size( ) );
System.out.println( "keywords: " + keywords );
System.out.println( "Done." );
```

Comment: FileReader always uses the platform default encoding which is generally not a good idea - you should probably use an InputStreamReader instead (and simlarly use an OutputStreamReader with the apprpriate charset for the writing part).